# 'tags' in logstash modifying 'tags' column from sql query

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a LogStash setup that will fetch data from Postgres. The problem is, I have a column called "tags" in SQL which is an array of strings. But during the insertion of data, the Logstash will append the "Logstash tag" into the tags array of my column. Is there any way to override that?

```
jdbc {
tags => "color_list"
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}"
jdbc_user => "${DB_USER}"
jdbc_password => "${DB_PASSWORD}"
schedule => "* * * * *"
jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
statement => "SELECT tags
    from color_table;"
```

In my table, the tags column is empty. So I am expecting an empty array. But am receiving `[color_list]` instead of `[]`. Is there any way to override that?

Answer (score 0):

Logstash manages "tags" on each event. It is some kind of metadata, that you can manupulate in your pipeline : all filters have [add_tag](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-add_tag) and remove_tag options, for example. Some filters will automatically add tags on failure (for example: grokparsefailure if the grok pattern doesn't match on the event's contents).

I would advise to not attempt to use the tags field for anything else.
I suggest you rename your field from the DB instead. How about this ?

```
statement => "SELECT tags as db_tags
    from color_table;"
```

Then in your doument you can process the [db_tags] field as you expect, and leave the [tags] field for logstash.